# What am I doing wrong with Scheme?

Tags: scheme

When I enter the following:

```
(define (root a b c)
   (/ (+ (-b) (sqrt (- (exp b 2) (* 4 a c)))) (* 2 a)))
```

and then enter:

```
(root 3 6 2)
```

I get a message indicating that the procedure had two arguments but only requires exactly one. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not suppose that you have a function `-b` defined; therefore, you most likely want a space between `-` and `b` in `(- b)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exp` function doesn't do exponents really, it does something else mathy. (I don't know.)

What you want is usually called `pow` for "power" but probably isn't defined in your environment, so I suggest you just define your own `square` method:

```
(define (square x) (* x x))
```

And then:

```
(define (root a b c)
   (/ (+ (- b) (sqrt (- (square b) (* 4 a c)))) (* 2 a)))
```

**Edit:** Oh, you'll also have to change a couple spacing issues, like `(* 4 a c)` instead of `(*4 a c)`, and `(- b)` instead of `(-b)`. You always have to separate the operator from the operands with spaces.

Comment: For the curious, `(exp n)` returns [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_number)^n. And Scheme does have a power function, but it's called `expt`

Answer (score 1):

The procedure `exp` raises the number `e` to the power of its argument, if you need to raise an argument to the power of another argument, use `expt`. Even better, given that you only need to square `b`, a simple multiplication will do. Like this:

```
(define (root a b c)
   (/ (+ (- b) (sqrt (- (* b b) (* 4 a c))))
      (* 2 a)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The function the error refers to is `exp` which takes only one argument.  The `exp` function calculates the exponential function, not an exponent.  You want `expt`, which raises a root `x` to the exponent `y`:

```
(expt b 2)
```

You can also just multiply the number times itself.

I usually keep [R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/) or The *Scheme Programming Language* on hand since these basic functions can be hard to keep straight.